# CORS in Meteor with Cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor, cors

I am ridiculously trying to get CORS working on Meteor 1.8, suddenly had this problem in my app:

*" I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.14/sockjs/info?cb=3lc2_ftamu' from origin 'http://localhost:12368' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", source: http://localhost:12368/ (0)"*

It only appears on Android and iOS, not when running web-only.

I searched all the stack overflow and Meteor help and forums, tried:

```
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return next();
});
```

Also tried in mobile_config.js:

```
App.accessRule('*');
```

I also tried other headers on the server, updated Meteor, tried with the *cors package*:

```
...
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

and all the other common things when Meteor Cordova isn't running.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I forgot the port (:3000) in the http-address for the root and mobile-server like so:

**http://localhost:3000**

So should be

**meteor run android --mobile-server http://ip-addr:3000**

Ip-addr should be your local IP address. 
I just forgot the :3000 to tell the Cordova version on Android that the app runs locally on port 3000.

Comment: could you edit your answer with the complete solution please? Which of the different options you tried are still needed?

Comment: Sorry the late edit since I unfortunately don't get email when people comment here.